# Performance issues with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When doing some React profiling on my Chrome DevTools, I see some styled components taking up to 100ms to run.

This is so weird, since they don't have complex code at all.

Here you can see a codesandbox with the component Spinner, which is actually running on our app and it takes more than 80ms to run.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-silence-6jmpp

If I remove the `${props => getType(props)};` line, then it drops to only 6ms.

Comment: I suspect from the import of gifs...

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: What is the performance problem on this code? why do these components take so long to run?